# what can i write in select tag instead of - Asp For="Propethy Name" in order to get the value selected from the list?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

this is part of my code that transfer data to another view in my

asp.net mvc project

```
               <link rel="stylesheet"

               <div class="wrapper">
               <select asp-for="@Model.Category.Name" id="choose" name="choose" class="form">                   

                <option value="Dog">Dog</option>

                <option value="Cat">Cat</option>

                <option value="Bird">Bird</option>   
             
                <option value="other">Other</option>   
             
                </select>

                  </div>

                <div class="mb-2">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

                </div>
```

i have 2 other propeties that i get with input tag that work fine , and in the select tag for some

reason i cant transfer the data throw.

tried to use some JS but it didnt work

Comment: The code in the OP is missing a double-quote (`"`).

Comment: @user9938 it doesnt work either way any ideas?

Comment: link tag above is unfinished

Comment: `link` tag is not closed.

Comment: @Mueller-Nico Doest work Regardless

Comment: You may consider use ' using @html.beginform()' to post. You can wrap around all the item to send back to your controller.

Comment: Are you using a Form element here? Also what you mean by transferring data to another view?

Answer (score 0):

> what can i write in select tag instead of - Asp For="Propethy Name" in
> order to get the value selected from the list?

You can try to remove `asp-for="@Model.Category.Name"` , and use name attribute  `name="choose"` to get the value selected from the list.
Below is a demo, you can refer to it.

HomeController:

```
       public IActionResult Selectlist()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Selectlist(string choose)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Selectlist View:

```
<form  asp-action="Selectlist">
    <div class="wrapper">
               <select  id="choose" name="choose" class="form">                   

                <option value="Dog">Dog</option>

                <option value="Cat">Cat</option>

                <option value="Bird">Bird</option>   
             
                <option value="other">Other</option>   
             
                </select>

                  </div>

                <div class="mb-2">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

                </div>

</form>
```

result:

[image]